# Inactive tabs on the S.O. profile page have no bottom border if a number box is present

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

[image]

If click on this tab, the indicator goes away and the border goes back to normal.

[image]

Comment: [No repro on Chrome latest (version 74)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKT19.png). What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox 66.0.5 on Mojave 10.14.4